# Laravel multiple orderBy from dynamic array input

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add orderBy clauses to a query dynamically.

**What I've tried**

```
$sort = Input::get('sort');

// Ex. of $sort below  
// Could be more or less key / values depending on user input
"category" => "asc",
"created_at" => "desc",
"email" => "asc",
"title" => "asc"

// I need to chain multiple orderBy's to a query
// but I can't use foreach in the laravel query
foreach ($sort as $key => $value) {
  echo "->orderBy(\"$key\", \"$value\")";
}
```

Is there a way to chain multiple orderBy's to an existing query?  Or a way to chain them during the creation of the query?

I am using [Bootgrid](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/) and trying to utilize it's multisort capabilities.

**Code update**

This is producing a status code 500.

```
$advertisements = DB::table('advertisements')
                    ->get();

foreach ($sort as $key => $value) {
    $advertisements->orderBy($key, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can add stuff to your query object after creating it like this:

```
<?php
$query = DB::table('advertisements');
foreach (Input::get('sort') as $key => $value) {
    $query->orderBy($key, $value);
}
$advertisements = $query->get();
```

Comment: Am I assigning the variable to the foreach?

Comment: @Rafael This just tacks on an extra `orderBy()` to your Laravel `$query` object for each sort value in your Input. I'm assuming you have instantiated a Laravel query builder object somewhere in your PHP, like `$query = DB::table('table_name')->where('field', '=', 'etc')`

Comment: @Rafael I see the problem from your update to your question. See how I've updated my answer - the `->get()` has to go last.